# Zooming when there are elements on top of a background pic

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have a form that is made up of a background image over which I put input elements. The problem is that when zooming in/out the page (i.e. pressing the zoom in the settings or ctrl & +/-) the elements move away from their current position on the background. 
The strange thing is this only happens in Chrome. In IE (8, 9, 10) it works perfectly. 
Also strange is that it seems only the checkboxes move funny but the textboxes are fine.
Please could someone give me an idea of what to do? Thanks
The link to the webpage is: http://www.webconcepts.co.il/landingPage/diraBituach/diraBituach.php

Answer (score 0):

solution for chrome

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0)
 .private {
    margin: 12px 238px 5px 0;
}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0)
`.shared {`
   margin: 14px 118px 0 0;
```

Comment: nope.. not working. looks like there are several mistakes in the syntax you used. Anyway, i tried it without the mistakes - nothing doing..

Comment: would you please post your HTML and CSS?

Comment: Click on the page source on the webpage (the css is in the header).... Sorry if its a bother...

Answer (score -1):

this may work try position:absolute;